# Decode a Python string

Tags: python-3.x, encoding

Sorry for the generic title.

I am receiving a string from an external source: `txt = external_func()`

I am copying/pasting the output of various commands to make sure you see what I'm talking about:

```
In [163]: txt
Out[163]: '\\xc3\\xa0 voir\\n'

In [164]: print(txt)
\xc3\xa0 voir\n

In [165]: repr(txt)
Out[165]: "'\\\\xc3\\\\xa0 voir\\\\n'"
```

I am trying to transform that text to UTF-8 (?) to have `txt = "à voir\n"`, and I can't see how.

How can I do transformations on this variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can encode your `txt` to a bytes-like object using the [encode-method of the str class.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)
Then this byte-like object can be decoded again with the [encoding `unicode_escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings).

Now you have your string with all escape sequences parsed, but `latin-1` decoded. You still have to encode it with `latin-1` and then decode it again with `utf-8`.

```
>>> txt = '\\xc3\\xa0 voir\\n'
>>> txt.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
'à voir\n'
```

The `codecs` module also has an [undocumented funciton](https://bugs.python.org/issue30588) called `escape_decode`:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.escape_decode(bytes('\\xc3\\xa0 voir\\n', 'utf-8'))[0].decode('utf-8')
'à voir\n'
```

Comment: Wow, a bit messy/convoluted, but thank you very much!

Comment: I am glad I could help you. You are right about the messy part, but I could not find any function, that does all in one step.